# How to make an AWS Step function task wait for a SNS Message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I need an AWS Step function with multiple steps as follows

```
Start >>
Step 1 [ Lambda ] >> 
Step 2 [ Lambda that calls itself multiple times and send out a SNS message when done ] >> 
Step 3 [ needs to be triggered only when the SNS message is received ] >>
End
```

How do I get Step 3 to wait for the SNS message ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, but you can send the result of step 2 to step 3 without using SNS

Make sure to read the doc on Output/Input/Result here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-input-output-filtering.html